# Integrate language service (MPF) and editor extension (MEF)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mef, extensibility, languageservice

Does anybody the correct way to integrate a languageService (MPF) with an editor extension (MEF) in Visual Studio 2010.

Where to implement the member completion, syntax highlight, quick info, etc.?

Any example avaliable?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MSDN [recommends](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885475.aspx) to use the new editor API, and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IPyIntegration) there is the source code of the IronPython integration solution.

Thanks to all!

Comment: How is this an answer? The MSDN recommendation is talking about how to update the language service assembly references - there is **no mention of MEF nor MPF**.  The IronPython code sample uses _MPF_ **not MEF**